# OpenGL/C++ Rotate relative to shooting gun

Tags: opengl, c++, rotate

I'm trying to make a 2D game where I have a gun that i use to shot things in the direction of the mouse resulting in an angle that I can get. I have some problems with the trajectory of the bullet because I don't know what to put in the Transpose and Rotate function.
For example Point 1 has x = 20 and y  = 30. I want to shot in the direction of Point 2  at x = 50 and y = 50. To do that i get an angle 't' which I use in the rotate function. But the reality is that I get the animation that I presented in the photo. I increase the x coord of the bullet because I can only shot in right side so only positive x. The bullet is moving on the 0x axis rotated at an angle t but at the same y as the gun.

[image]

What I want is something like

[image]

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate I couldn't find a solution to my problem. I think the resulting Matrix should have the form : Translate * Rotate * Translate but I can't find the right x and y.

Sorry if this seemed dumb and thank you for your time!

Comment: I can't post a full answer now, but if you look online, there are ways to find the angle of a triangle, based on its sides. From your figures, create a `Point 3`, that is sitting directly below `Point 2` on the same `y` as `Point 1`. That will create a triangle with a square angle, and should make it easier to calculate the other two angles.

Comment: If your gun is at `(x0,y0)` and your mouse is at `(x1,y1)` then you can work out the angle with `atan((y1-y0)/(x1-x0))` You'd need to do some very simple Mechanics, taking into account gravity and acceleration to create a parabolic path `(rx,ry)` which you'd use as the position of your projectile over time `t`. You'd need this formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Time_of_flight_or_total_time_of_the_whole_journey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say you are shooting from `p1` with coordinates `p1.x` and `p1.y`. And you want to shoot in direction to `p2` with coordinates `p2.x` and `p2.y`.

When the bullet is created, you will place it in `p1`. That would be something like this:

```
bullet.position = p1;
```

---

We need to figure out how it should move.

Let us call `d` the vector that goes from `p1` to `p2`:

```
d = p2 - p1
d = (p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y)
```

*If you want the angle `t`, it will be `t = atan2(d.y, d.x)` or `t = atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)` if you prefer. You don't need the angle.*

Let us say that the bullet should advance `speed` distance per unit for time. Then your velocity is:

```
velocity = d * speed/length(d)
```

That `velocity` describes the motion of the bullet. *I'm assuming no gravity, as it was not mentioned in the question. I'm guessing this is a top down game.*

I suggest to store it in the bullet:

```
bullet.position = p1;

var d = p2 - p1;
bullet.velocity = d * speed/length(d);
```

Each game cycle you will move the bullet by `velocity` according to the number of units of times elapsed. That would be something like this:

```
bullet.position = bullet.position + (bullet.velocity * delta);
```

where `delta` is the elapsed time in the same units used for `l`. For example `l` is pixels per millisecond and `delta` is milliseconds. If you are working with different units you need a unit conversion. For example if `l` is pixels per second, and `delta` is milliseconds, you need to divide delta by 1000 so it is in seconds.

---

The vector operations used:

- Vector addition: `v1 + v2 = (v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y)`
- Vector subtraction: `v1 - v2 = (v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y)`
- Scalar product: `v * s = (v.x * s, v.y * s)`
- Length: `length(v) = sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y)`

---

Alright, let us suppose you are placing a model to represent the bullet, and you want to be able to apply a transformation to the model.

We want to have the orientation stored so we have use it to orient the model.

```
bullet.position = p1;

var d = p2 - p1;
bullet.direction = d * 1/length(d);
bullet.velocity = bullet.direction * speed;
```

Let us see how the rotation matrix transformation looks like:

```
+-                  -+
|  cos(θ)    -sin(θ) |
|                    |
|  sin(θ)    cos(θ)  |
+-                  -+
```

We already have those values:

```
+-                                          -+
|  bullet.direction.x    -bullet.direction.y |
|                                            |
|  bullet.direction.y    bullet.direction.x  |
+-                                          -+
```

And, of course, you would make your translation matrix from `bullet.position`.

*There is no need to call any trigonometric function. No need to waste CPU cycles on them or introduce floating point errors due their computation.*